# Excel VBA Countifs with wildcard criteria - for dates

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard, countif

I would like to know if I can use a wildcard for dates?

I have dates with time stored on A1:A5 and I want to count how many items are
there with criteria "8/12/2015" regardless of the time, the output *compl* should be 2 as A1 and A4 contains the date "8/12/2015"

A1 = 8/12/2015 12:00 AM

A2 = 8/25/2015 3:00 PM

A3 = 8/23/2015 4:00 AM

A4 = 8/12/2015 1:30 AM

A5 = 8/20/2015 12:00 AM

```
            Sub counter()

            With Sheet1
            Dim compl As String
            Dim xdate As String, xdate2 As String
            xdate = "08/12/2015"
            xdate2 = xdate & "*"

            compl = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("a1:a5"), xdate2)
                Debug.Print compl
            End With

            End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your date is a date, not a string.

Make sure to use ISO standard formats, not some random date order.

```
Dim xdate As date
xdate = "2015-08-12"

compl = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("a1:a5"), ">=" & xdate, _
                                   Range("a1:a5"), "<" & (xdate + 1))
```

Also, you don't need VBA for this, simply use the Excel's COUNTIFS function like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(a1:a5,">=2015-08-28",a1:a5,"<2015-08-29")
```

**Edit**
For me, adding the Format function was necessary to keep the date in a human format for Excel to understand. Change the Worksheetfunction line like this, if you want to make sure it works:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("a1:a5"), ">=" & Format(xdate, "yyyy-mm-dd"), _
                           Range("a1:a5"), "<" & Format(xdate + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

Comment: thank you very much! sorry I'm very new to excel VBA,

Answer (score 0):

In Excel the date are stored as numbers since 1/1/1970. this means that the date you wrote is 42239.
When the the 2 decimal digits are the hours. sou you can use the function `round`  (with 0 digits)  when this number will include all the cells in the specific date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Balinti I tried that process but when I convert the date into Number there will be a decimal equivalent for time. Is there any code to compare by wildcard for numbers to disregard the decimal places?

ex. A1 contains 42239.97 

the code below doesn't work:

x = 42239
xdate2 = 42239 & "*"
compl = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("a1:a5"), xdate2)

Comment: you can use format with Format(Date, "MM_DD_YYYY") as well

Comment: I dont seem to understand where I will use the format syntax, sorry can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't has to be in VBA and countif (I don't see what is the goal):
=sumproduct((floor(value(A1:A5),1)=date(2015,8,20))*1)
otherwise there are options for cycles and so on, but without the purpose it's hard to point for the right direction

Comment: Ok, I forgot always, that I work in a company with technology from the last millenia.

Comment: I used vba because I have thousands of records that I pull out from MS Access DB table, the table contains personel name, task, status of task (e.g. completed, in-progress, cancelled), date completed/cancelled for my report which shows how many task has been completed/cancelled/inprogress by personel name on a specified date or week or month.

Comment: Ok. Vacips answer should be then the appropiate way.
If it's possible I calculate all the needed data in SQL, or when it's populated (in a cycle) using fields values and VBA functions.